# Execute process as current Mac OS X user, not as root

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, root, launchd

I have created a Mac OS X helper application that always runs under root. I need to launch other application from it, but **not** as root. I want it to be launched from the current logged in user (not sudoed root).

I've tried to use `[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:arguments:]` and many other methods, but they all use root privileges to launch my application.

How can I launch my application from helper as a current Mac OS X logged in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [Authorization Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/authorization_concepts/03authtasks/authtasks.html) might help you.

Comment: Please be more specific. What part of it directly addresses the question?

Comment: In unix, I think you'd want to set the euid for the process, so I did a search for Mac and euid.  There's a section in there **Calling a Helper Tool as Root** that talks about running a sub-process as root.  I don't know if it goes the other way, but it's a place to start.